# What is the best way to get historical stock data?

Tags: python, yahoo-finance

I have a list of 1500 tickers, and I need to get 95 days of historical data for each one of them.
Can anyone recommend a fast and reliable* way to get historical stock data? (I'm using .get_data_yahoo).

* sometimes .get_data_yahoo command ends with all kinds of errors...

Thank you!

Comment: What is `pdr` or `web`? Does your code set `pdr = web`, for example? In that case, there is no difference

Answer (score 1):

Answer to unedited question: I assume you are using the package [pandas-datareader](https://pandas-datareader.readthedocs.io) and when it is imported it is abbreviated with either `pdr` or `web` but both names refer to the same object (you can use any name you like):

```
import pandas_datareader as pdr

pdr.get_data_yahoo('GS10')
```

is the same as

```
import pandas_datareader as web

web.get_data_yahoo('GS10')
```